# How to run react native expo project on 2 emulators on MacOS M1

Tags: android, react-native, expo, android-emulator, adb

I'm running the project by

```
expo run:android
```

and it runs in emulator.. it's okay
And I want to run project on 2 emulators
So I have a list of devices:

```
List of devices attached
emulator-5554   device
emulator-5556   device
```

And I want to run expo project like:

```
expo run:android -d emulator-5554
```

or something like this, is it possible?